# Getting unique elements from a column returns one value

Tags: powershell

I have the following function defined in a ps1 file, using the DLL from the [latest taglib release](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TagLibSharp/2.2.0#). I downloaded the nuget package and ran `expand-archive` on it and copied the DLL to the correct place.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Resolve-Path ($PSScriptRoot + "\TagLibSharp.dll")))
function Get-Image {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)] $Name
    )

    process {
        $fullPath = (Resolve-Path $Name).Path
        $image = [taglib.file]::create($fullpath)

        return $image
    }
}

function Get-ImmediatePhotos {
    Get-ChildItem | Where-Object  {$_.Extension -eq ".jpg" -or $_.Extension -eq ".png"} | Get-Image
}
```

When I run this command to extract the years from the EXIF data in photos in a given directory I get a table like this:

```
> $years = Get-ImmediatePhotos | select-object {$_.Tag.DateTime.Year}
> $years
$_.Tag.DateTime.Year
--------------------
                2020
                2020
                2020
                2020
                2020
                2020
                2020
                2020
                2020
                2020
                2021
                2021
                2021
                2021
```

If I then try to extract unique years with `sort-object` I only get one year!

```
> $years | sort-object -unique

$_.Tag.DateTime.Year
--------------------
                2020
```

If I try to group years with `group-object` I get this error:

```
$years | group-object
Group-Object: Cannot compare "@{$_.Tag.DateTime.Year=2020}" to
"@{$_.Tag.DateTime.Year=2020}" because the objects are not the same type or the object 
"@{$_.Tag.DateTime.Year=2020}" does not implement "IComparable".
```

This seems to be telling me that the type of values in the column are some sort of anonymous thing which can't be compared.

How do I use the results of select as values, such as strings?  My end goal is to automatically sort and categorize photos into directories in `/year/month` format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your calculated property a proper **name** so that you can reference it later when using `Sort-Object` or `Group-Object`:

```
$years = Get-ImmediatePhotos | select-object @{Name='YearTaken';Expression={$_.Tag.DateTime.Year}}

$years |Sort-Object YearTaken -Unique
# or 
$years |Group-Object YearTaken
```

---

Altenatively, use `ForEach-Object` instead of `Select-Object` - `ForEach-Object` will spit out the raw `Year` values (as opposed to an object having the value stored in a nested property, which is what `Select-Object` gives you):

```
$years = Get-ImmediatePhotos | ForEach-Object {$_.Tag.DateTime.Year}

# `$years` is just an array of raw Year values now, no need to specify a key property
$years |Sort-Object -Unique
# or 
$years |Group-Object
```

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67938269/45375) with **why what you tried didn't work**:

The immediate problem is that **[`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object)`-Unique` considers all `[pscustomobject]` instances to be *equal*, even if they have different property values, and even if they have different sets of properties**.

- Note  that **your [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call**, due to use of the (positionally implied) `-Property` parameter, **does *not* extract just the *years* from its input objects, but creates a `[pscustomobject]` wrapper object *with a property*** containing the year.
- Normally, `-ExpandProperty` is used to extract just the *values* of a single property, but with a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), such as in your case, this doesn't work. However, passing the exact same script block to [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) does work.

Therefore, to make your original code work, you need to pass the name of the properties whose values should be sorted and used as the basis for the uniqueness determination:

```
$years | sort-object -unique -property '$_.Tag.DateTime.Year'
```

Note the strange property name, which results from your `Select-Object` call having used just a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) as a calculated property, in which case the script block's *literal source code* becomes the property name (the result of calling `.ToString()` on the script block).

Typically, a [*hashtable*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) is used to define a calculated property, which allows  *naming* the property, as shown in Mathias' answer.

---

As an aside: If you want **to merely *sort* by year while passing the original image objects through**, you can use your script block as-is directly with `Sort-Object`'s (positionally implied) `-Property` parameter:

```
# Sort by year, but output the image objects.
Get-ImmediatePhotos | Sort-Object {$_.Tag.DateTime.Year}
```

Note that in this use of a calculated property, direct use of a script block is appropriate and usually sufficient, as the property is purely used for sorting, and doesn't require a name.

However, **`Sort-Object` too supports *hashtable*-based calculated properties**, but such hashtables do *not* support a `name` / `label` entry (because it would be meaningless), but **you can use either `ascending` or `descending` as a Boolean entry to control the sort order on a per-property basis**.

That is, the following is the verbose equivalent of the command above:

```
Get-ImmediatePhotos | Sort-Object @{ ascending=$true; expression={$_.Tag.DateTime.Year} }
```